# How do I find duplicate keys in static JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, static

Here's what I tried.

```
try {
     var obj = {"name":"n","name":"v"};
     console.log(obj); // outputs { name: 'v' }
} catch (e) {
     console.log(e); // no exceptions printed
}
```

I want to find duplicate keys in a huge static Javascript object with standard tools.

Comment: Is this question appropriate yet?  Is it a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

It's not eliminating keys just you overwrote it. Since keys are unique in objects only the last assignation remains.

A possible alternative for you could be to wrap those elements in an array:

```
  {
    "names":[
       {"name":"n"},
       {"name":"v"}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. What happens is that the second declaration overwrites the first declaration. Have duplicate key values at the same level in JSON isn't valid. Instead of throwing an error the Javascript JSON module decides to handle it gracefully and override as defined by the Javascript spec

Comment: David, you are wrong.  It is not the correct answer.  You guys didn't answer the question.  I said "why silently in static objects"  This plainly is a programmer error.  I want to eliminate duplicate keys in static objects.  I'm not going to do that if my JavaScript object is 40 pages long and no error is reported.  "use strict" is more correct.  Please vote it back up.

Comment: Also "use strict" doesn't work with JSON parsers I am familiar with.  They ignore duplicates anyway.

Comment: Yes I realize some so called JSON parsers accept duplicate keys.  The issue is how to get rid of or detect duplicate keys.

Comment: I don't need an alternative format for my JavaScript objects,  I need to find objects with duplicate keys.   If you want to provide JavaScript for a deeply nested object, that would be cool.

Answer (score -2):

If you enable strict mode, JavaScript will throw an exception if you define an object literal with duplicate keys;

```
"use strict";

try {
    var obj = {"name":"n","name":"v"};
    console.log(obj);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

EDIT:  This only works in ECMAScript 5, not ECMAScript 6.  According to "Understanding ECMAScript 6."  I haven't tried it yet.